# How to configure WildFly Port for Vaadin Application

Tags: wildfly, java-ee-6, vaadin8

i have a Vaadin 8 Application with 2 WebServlets. I want to make it possible to connect to the second Servlet with a specific Port.

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "MainUIServlet", asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = MainUI.class, productionMode = false)
public static class MainUIServlet extends VaadinServlet {

@WebServlet(value = {"/admin/*", "/VAADIN/*"}, name = "AdminUIServlet", asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = AdminUI.class, productionMode = false)
public static class AdminUIServlet extends VaadinServlet {
```

These are the two servlets. I want to make it possible that when i type "example.application.com:1111" that it will connect to the "AdminUIServlet". But without the vhost config from the Apache. Is it possible to bind the Port to the Servlet?

When i use the 9990 Port i get access to the Wildfly Manager, exactly like that i want to get access to the specific servlet of my Application just with the Port 1111

Comment: Check if this brings any help for you, there is nothing Vaadin specific here. Vaadin is just like any other servlet from Wildfly perspective. https://www.baeldung.com/wildfly-change-default-port

Comment: but in this article its about to change the default port. The default port should stay the same, i want a second port for the second servlet which is  in the same application. Hope this explains better what i want..